# I want to redirect value from controller to jsp page in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

Here is my democontroller.java

```
package com.viewsite.model.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.Action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import com.plotwell.Dao.MyConnection;

public class democontroller extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private String uact;


    public String getUact() {
        return uact;
    }

    public void setUact(String uact) {
        this.uact = uact;
    }


    @Override
    public void setSession(Map<String, Object> arg0) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public String execute() throws SQLException, IOException,ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
            //democontroller object = new democontroller();
            System.out.println("uact aa gaya"+getUact());
            String uaact = getUact();
            return "graphs/jsp/demo.jsp";

    }
}
```

here is my demo.jsp page

```
<%@page import="com.viewsite.model.controller.democontroller"%>
<%@page import="com.viewsite.model.controller.ClientDropdown"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware" %>
<%@ page import="com.plotwell.Dao.MyConnection"%>
<%@ page import="com.login.model.LoginAction" %>
<%@ page import="com.plotwell.model.SiteInfo" %>
<%@ page import="com.viewsite.model.controller.ClientDropdown" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
<%
    ClientDropdown cd = new ClientDropdown();
    democontroller obj = new democontroller();
    System.out.println("idhar bhi aa gaya" +obj.getUact());

    System.out.println("inside scriptlet");
    session.getAttribute("id");
    LoginAction loginAction = new LoginAction();
    String id = loginAction.getId();
    System.out.println("in client:::"+session.getAttribute("id"));
    MyConnection conn = new MyConnection();
    SiteInfo siteInfo = new SiteInfo();
    try{
        Connection con = conn.getconnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM graph WHERE ucid = ? ");
        ps.setString(1, (String)session.getAttribute("id"));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        //System.out.println("data "+rs.getString("uact"));
            /* System.out.println("data "+rs.getString("uact"));
            String uact=rs.getString("uact");
            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM transaction WHERE uact = '"+uact+"' order by instno" );
            ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
            while(rs1.next()){
                //System.out.println("tid  "+rs1.getString("tid"));
            } */ 



%>
<script type="text/javascript">
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Total paid amount according to Installment NO'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: <a href="cluebix.com">Cluebix</a>'
    },
    xAxis: {
     title: {
            text: 'Install no'
        },
       categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
                    '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14','15',
                    '16','17', '18','19', '20','21', '22','23', '24','25', '26','27', '28','29', '30'] 
   },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'paid amount'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'paid amount: <b>{point.y:.1f} </b>'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Site Name',
        data: [

               <%
               while(rs.next()) 
            { 
               System.out.println("tid  "+rs.getString("uact"));   
               %>

            ['<%=rs.getString("uact")%>', <%=rs.getString("paidamt")%>],

            <%
         }
            %>

        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: -90,
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: 10, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
});
</script>

<%
    ps.close();
con.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { 
        out.clear();
        out = pageContext.pushBody();
        out.println("Page Not Found");
    } 
%>

</html>
```

In above controller I get value of uact from ajax call but now I want this value on demo.jsp.

How can I redirect this value from controller to jsp page.

This will will help me to make graph.

I tried many  times but fail.

Comment: by calling another controller may be you should know that ajax calls not always fail and the caching should be turned off to make the value to appear where it's expected.

Answer (score 1):

That code is a complete nonsense.

1. You don't

   > *get the value of uact from an ajax call*

,you are getting it from the getter, that reads the uact variable, and then you are assigning it back to the same variable. *Escher, anyone ?*

2. You're returning the path of a JSP, but you must return a result, mapped to a JSP in the struts.xml file. This is the basic of Struts2.
3. You are heavily using scriptlets (`<% %>`) in your JSP page; scriptlets are bad. No matter what, never use sctiplets again. Never, never, ever. Use Struts2 tags, or JSTL tags, or JSP EL, or whatever. Not scriptlets.

After fixing the errors in your business logic, in your result mapping and in your JSP structure, you'll not have any of the problems you have now.

You'll probably have other problems / doubts, but by then you should be able to come back here asking a question that is *really* answerable.

Comment: ok sir,I'll make changes in it,Thank you so much for your valuable guidance.